# Hashing the value to the api

Tags: php, coldfusion, lucee

I had this code

```
  $params = $version.$merchant_id.$payment_description.$order_id.$currency.$amount.$result_url_1;
    $hash_value = hash_hmac('sha256',$params, $secret_key,false);
```

converted to CF as

```
     param = version & merchant_id & payment_description & order_id & currency & amount & result_url_1,"SHA-256")>
hash_value = lcase(hash(param & secret_key,"SHA-256')>
```

But data is different , am i missing anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The php code (first code snippet) is using `hash_hmac`, which requires a shared key to produce the hash, as the code shows. Your CF code (second code snippet) only uses a normal `hash` function.

You cannot simply concatenate the param and secret like you do. It will not result in the same hash as your php code. You need to use the `HMac` function of CF, and use it in the same way as the php code, keeping the secret as a separate parameter to the hmac function.

See reference: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-h-im/hmac.html

As stated by the user, the CF `HMac` function returns a hash in UPPERcase, while the PHP `hash_mac` function returns the hash in lowercase. To be able to compare the 2 as strings, convert the CF `HMac` to lowercase by wrapping it in a `LCase` function.

Comment: i missed that first line is also using `hash_hmac` of php code

Comment: Well, the php code is using `hash_hmac`, which requires a shared key to produce the hash, as the code shows. Your CF code only uses normal hash function. You cannot simply concatenate the param and secret like you do. It will not result in the same hash as your php code. You need to use the `hmac` function of CF, and use it in the same way as the php code, keeping the secret as a separate parameter to the hmac function.

Comment: so how is it then, can't find hmac function in coldfusion

Comment: I'm not a coldfusion expert, but doesn't this work: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-h-im/hmac.html

Comment: this function exists, just now i came to know, Thanks all

Comment: May also want to update the answer to reflect the changes in the question.

Comment: @MaartenVeerman - Looks good. Only thing I'd add is to note that CF result string is always be in upper case. If for some reason case matters, wrap the hmac() result in lcase() to match the php results exactly. https://trycf.com/gist/a4cc8f872d10e46f9f59a488d34b4b20/lucee5?theme=monokai